# Can hyper be used in TikZ graphs and, if so, how?

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, luatex, graphs, tikz-graphs

I am trying to compile the example from page 390 of the Ti*k*Z manual.

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing,graphs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \graph {
    % The nodes:
    a, b, c, d;
    % The edges:
    {[hyper] a,b,c};
    {[hyper] b,c,d};
    {[hyper] a,c};
    {[hyper] d}
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However, I get the following error.

```
/pgf/graphdrawing/lua/pgf/gd/interface/InterfaceCore.lua:100: no graph drawing 
scope open
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'assert'
        .../pgf/graphdrawing/lua/pgf/gd/interface/InterfaceCore.lua:100: in function '
topScope'
        ...graphdrawing/lua/pgf/gd/interface/InterfaceToDisplay.lua:590: in function '
pushOption'
        [\directlua]:1: in main chunk.
\pgf@gd@handle@parameter ...riggerrequest }') end}

l.136   }
       ;
?
```

Is this because

> Currently, there is no default renderer for hyper edges. (389)

and, if so, how is this intended to be used? Is it just a place-holder for attaching a renderer?

Comment: The manual does not give an example figure at all... I guess the author has no time to write a renderer and expects users to write one.

Comment: The content you quoted comes from `.../model/Hyperedge.lua`. This file contains nothing functional, only some explanation.

Comment: @Symbol1 Thanks. That's what I suspected just from the manual, but it seemed very odd to give an example in this case. (Certainly it would be nice if the manual were a little more explicit with regards to the example e.g. including a comment line `% By default, this will draw nothing.` ;)